# how to center align list items inside the div?

Tags: html, css

I have page links in my footer which are left aligned in large screens. I want to center align them in extra small screen. The left align looks messy in extra small screen. I want to center align them like in the picture i have included. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp0j1m0r/)

[image]

Here is what i have tried

```
.footer-link{
margin: 20px 0;
margin-left: 15px;
}

.footer-link>ul>li{
margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
font-family: gotham_book;
font-weight: bold;
color: #424242;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
}
```

I tried to align it center. But it doesn't work. How do i center them like i showed in the picture.

```
<div class=" col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 footer-link padding-lr-zero">

     <ul class="footer-links list-inline">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Disclosures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: add `text-align: center;` in place of `text-align: left;`

Comment: you can also use <center> tag around the element that you wanna center

Comment: add this line in css ``.footer-link>ul {
  text-align: center
}``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.footer-links{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: this worked. I was giving alignment for the `<li>` and not to the `<ul>`. That was my mistake. Thank you

Comment: @NaveenKumar Mark the answer as "the answer", so everyone knows that the question got answered.

Answer (score 0):

change..

```
.footer-link>ul>li{
margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
font-family: gotham_book;
font-weight: bold;
color: #424242;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
```

}

replece this code

```
.footer-link>ul>li{
margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
font-family: gotham_book;
font-weight: bold;
color: #424242;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css code.

`.list-inline{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
}`

This will center the element on responsive too

```css
.footer-link{
 margin: 20px 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

.footer-link>ul>li{
 margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
 font-family: gotham_book;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #424242;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}
.list-inline{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
}
```

```html
          <div class=" col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 footer-link padding-lr-zero">

              <ul class="footer-links list-inline">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Disclosures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ul.footer-links li{
font-family: gotham_book;
font-weight: bold;
color: #424242;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

ul.footer-links li a{
font-size: 14px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

ul.footer-links {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer-link{
 margin: 20px 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

.footer-link>ul>li{
 margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
 font-family: gotham_book;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #424242;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <div class=" col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 footer-link padding-lr-zero text-center">

              <ul class="footer-links list-inline">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Disclosures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Just Use text-center class for your required execution. Try it once its effects only the screen width in minimum otherwise it's in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries for that, here is a list of bootstrap screne sizes media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 979px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

You should add to you CSS

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
 .footer-link>ul>li{
    text-align: center;
}
 }
}
```

here is a snippet

```css
.footer-link{
 margin: 20px 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

.footer-link>ul>li{
 margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
 font-family: gotham_book;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #424242;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
 .footer-link>ul>li{
 text-align: center;
}
 }
}
```

```html
          <div class=" col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 footer-link padding-lr-zero">

              <ul class="footer-links list-inline">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Disclosures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only Add**  `text-align: center;` in `ul` Tag  **or** `.footer-link` Class

```
.footer-link
{
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/rp0j1m0r/6/)

**Snippet**

```css
.footer-link {
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-link>ul>li {
  margin: 10px 4.2% 10px 0%;
  font-family: gotham_book;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class=" col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 footer-link padding-lr-zero">

  <ul class="footer-links list-inline">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Disclosures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `margin:auto`
if it doesn't work you will have to use **media tags**